# Assigning a missing rating to a date based on a rating on a different date

Tags: vba, loops, ms-access

I have a list of company (CoID) ratings (Rating) that were applied on a certain date (RatingDate).

The rating dates are sporadic, and I am looking to fill in the blanks by assigning the given rating to a specific date from a list of dates.

If the rating changes on a given RatingDate, the new rating is carried forward on the dates after the change.
My code carries forward the oldest rating, and doesn't change if the rating changes on a certain date.

```vb
Public Function PopulateTableOfRatingHistory()
    
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    
    Dim dtDate As Date 'snapshot date
    Dim sqlAppend As String
    
    Dim sqlQueryLastRating As String
       
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs1 = dbs.OpenRecordset("DATES") 'check this to make sure it imports the table values
    
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        
    rs1.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rs1.EOF
        'get the date value to use as a parameter
        dtDate = rs1.Fields(1).Value ' get the date value to lookup
        
        'use the date parameter to run the SQL for the last rating as of the given date and append the query result to a table
            
        DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblCoDtRtgs (ISIN, CoID, SnapDate, Rating, RatingDate ) SELECT RatingsBackDated.ISIN, RatingsBackDated.CoID, #" & dtDate & "#, Last(RatingsBackDated.Rating) AS LastOfRating, Last(RatingsBackDated.Date) AS LastOfDate " & _
          "FROM RatingsBackDated " & _
          "WHERE (((RatingsBackDated.Date)<= #" & dtDate & "#)) " & _
          "GROUP BY RatingsBackDated.name, RatingsBackDated.CoID, RatingsBackDated.ISIN;"
        
        rs1.MoveNext
    Loop
        
    rs1.Close
    Set rs1 = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
      
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
      
End Function
```

Comment: Edit question to show sample data and desired result - as text tables, not image.

Comment: Aggregate functions First and Last are unreliable without defining sort order. Review https://support.office.com/en-us/article/First-Last-Functions-ACD76019-C37F-432D-9807-4FC63CAC1DB5

Comment: Date and Name are reserved words and really should not use reserved words as names for anything.

Answer (score 0):

Consider pure SQL without looping where you first populate your table with a cross join for all combinations of `ISIN`, `CoID`, `SnapDate`, `Rating`, `RatingDate`, then use nested domain aggregates:

1. `DMax` to find the latest `RatingDate` relative to `SnapDate` by `CoId`
2. `DLookUp` to retrieve the specific `Rating` on the step 1 date by `CoId`

Both queries can be handled outside (via Access GUI Query Design > `! Run`) or inside VBA as shown below.

**SQL**

Append Query *(with cross join of comma separated tables)*

```sql
INSERT INTO tblCoDtRtgs (ISIN, CoID, SnapDate, Rating, RatingDate ) 
SELECT r.ISIN, r.CoID, d.[Date], r.Rating, r.[Date]
FROM (SELECT ISIN, CoID,  Rating, [Date], FROM RatingsBackDated) r, 
      Dates d;
```

Update Query *(with domain aggregates to be updateable)*

```sql
UPDATE tblCoDtRtgs r
SET r.Rating = DLookUp("Rating", "tblCoDtRtgs", 
                       "RatingDate = #" & NZ(DMax("RatingDate", "tblCoDtRtgs", 
                                               "[Date] < #" & r.Date & "#
                                                AND CoId = " & r.CoID),
                                             CDate('1900-01-01')) & "#
                        AND CoId = " & r.CoID);
```

**VBA**

```
' WITH WARNINGS (NO NEED TO CLOSE ACTION QUERIES)
DoCmd.OpenQuery myAppendQuery
DoCmd.OpenQuery myUpdateQuery


' WITHOUT WARNINGS
CurrentDb.Execute myAppendQuery
CurrentDb.Execute myUpdateQuery
```

Comment: Thank you very much for getting back to me, I won't have a chance to try this out until tomorrow but I will let you know how it goes!

Comment: The append query says "The select statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing or the punctuation is incorrect", and the update query says "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression", any ideas?  Thank you again.

Comment: I edited the syntax issue and having tested now in Access, I reversed previous logic for `DMax` and flipped inequality sign without equals and added `NZ`.

Answer (score 0):

> .. doesn't change if the rating changes on a certain date.

You probably need proper formatting of the expression for the date value - and you might wish to use *Max*, not *Last*:

```vb
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblCoDtRtgs (ISIN, CoID, SnapDate, Rating, RatingDate ) " & _
            "SELECT RatingsBackDated.ISIN, RatingsBackDated.CoID, #" & Format(dtDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#, Max(RatingsBackDated.Rating) AS LastOfRating, Max(RatingsBackDated.Date) AS LastOfDate " & _
            "FROM RatingsBackDated " & _
            "WHERE (((RatingsBackDated.Date)<= #" & Format(dtDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#)) " & _
            "GROUP BY RatingsBackDated.name, RatingsBackDated.CoID, RatingsBackDated.ISIN;"
```

Comment: Thank you Gustav, this unfortunately resulted in the same result, it is returning the data with the new dates, but it is only also returning the oldest rating, and not updating it when it changes.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by changing:
Last(RatingsBackDated.Rating) AS LastOfRating, Last(RatingsBackDated.Date) AS LastOfDate " & _

to:
Min(RatingsBackDated.Rating) AS MinOfRating, Max(RatingsBackDated.Date) AS MaxOfDate " & _

Thank you to everyone for the help.